# Rename the latest created file in a directory in linux

Tags: bash

I can get the latest modified/created file in a directory using the command

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

I would like to rename the file returned by the above command. How could i do that ?

I also tried something very rudimentary like this

```
ls -rt | xargs | awk {'print $1'} | xargs cat >> newfile.txt
```

Sometimes it works but mostly it just writes an empty file

Comment: `ls -rt | xargs | awk {'print $1'} | xargs cat >> newfile.txt   ` That's one of the most curios lines I've seen... what does the xargs and awk do in there? Why does `ls -At | head -n 1 | xargs "-I{}" mv "{}" newfile.txt` not work?

Comment: @Bobby That works. I'm new to shell scripting and i wasn't using xargs and awk the way it was supposed to be used in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `find` to identify recently modified files instead of parsing `ls`

```
find /path/to/search -type f -printf ‘%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n’ | sort -r | head -n1 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' newfile.txt
```

Comment: This works, but is there any advantage that the find command holds over ls ?

Comment: Thanks, if it is better to use find over ls i'll accept yours as the answer.

Comment: Accepted answer doesn't work (any more?) - the output that reaches the `xargs` has a timestamp plus a filename, so the `mv` command fails.  Separately the curly quotes should be regular quotes. plonker13 answer is similar but has a `cut` as well.

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
ls -ltr | awk '{ field = $NF }; END{ print field }' | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' newfile.txt
```

Comment: @devnull This will break for file name with spaces.

Comment: @Jaypal Oh yes, not only file name with spaces, it'd also break for symbolic links.  Won't it?  Who in the world would want to do such stuff using `ls`?

Answer (score 1):

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\n" | sort -n | cut -d' ' -f 2- | tail -n 1 | xargs -I '{}' mv '{}' newfile.txt
```

This will work in the current directory. For a different directory, change the path right after `find`.

This works if the filename has spaces.

It also ignores directories.